# Maven: Filter a web.xml in an overlay of a web project

Tags: maven, overlay, filtering, web.xml

So i got some critical Servlets in my webapplication which shall not reach prod but are used for testing. The path is secured with special rights, but as the rights have to be configured on every server correctly, there could be a security leak. My idea was to alter the deployment descriptor so only the web.xml for dev has the necessary configurations.

Therefore i created variables in my web.xml file to inject my servlets in dev environment. I got 2 filter files, 1 which replaces the constants with an empty string and the other for the servlet configuration.

I got 2 executions (1 default and 1 with classifier dev) which point to the right filter files. I use filteringDeploymentDescriptors and the path to the filter.

This works perfectly fine.

But now I need to also create a default and a dev war file for my 2 overlay projects. Unfortunatly it seems as if the web.xml is already filtered in the step when packing the overlay projects.

I welcome any ideas of how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!